# WP7 C# Retrieve access tokens of Google OAuth 2.0 request

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, google-oauth

I followed [this guide](http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/google-oauth-2-0-on-windows-phone/#respond) to use Google OAuth 2.0 authorization, but I can't understand how to implement request to retrieve access and refresh token in my Application. The code, as that guide say, is the current:

```
// Request an access token    
OAuthAuthorization authorization = new OAuthAuthorization(
"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
TokenPair tokenPair = await authorization.Authorize(
        ClientId,
        ClientSecret,
        new string[] {GoogleScopes.CloudPrint, GoogleScopes.Gmail});


// Request a new access token using the refresh token (when the access token was expired)
TokenPair refreshTokenPair = await authorization.RefreshAccessToken(
        ClientId,
        ClientSecret,
        tokenPair.RefreshToken);
```

Where and how can I call this function in a generic Windows Phone application?

(Sorry if there this question it's duplicate, but I try to search and I only find as answers links to generic Google Apis guide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call it when it's necessary (when you need to get tokens). After that use official Google libraries to get access to API and provide them data from TokenPair. Plus, remember to get this (https://github.com/pieterderycke/MobileOAuth/blob/master/MobileOAuth/GoogleScopes.cs) in your project, so you can use GoogleScopes.

Comment: Mmm, I tried to compile my Youtube application with official Dotnet libraries that are PCL, but everytime it couldn't run at startup....I don't know if a problem with Windows Phone 7 or another reason...